# Windows runtime library dependencies and pure C code

Tags: c++, c, windows, linker, libraries

For C++ on Windows, it is important that all libraries being linked together have been compiled with the same C++ Runtime Library. Does the same apply for pure C code?

More specific, I want to release a SDK for many difference Visual Studio versions, both static and dynamic. This SDK is linked with libpng which is a C project (not C++). Do I still have to build one binary of libpng for every Visual Studio version or is the C part of the runtime libraries the same?

Comment: It depends on the specific code.  If different modules use different C runtime instances, there are a number of things you need to check, e.g., that the module that frees a chunk of memory is always the same one that allocated it; that you don't try to send C runtime streams across module boundaries; that you don't use errno or other global variables across the module boundaries; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Even with pure C code you cannot have a situation where memory allocated with malloc in one module is freed in another module. It is not simply a question of using the same version of the library: In order to support such cross-module memory operations the modules must be using the same **instance** of the library.